# Seating five people with one person can only sit in $k$ of the $5$ chairs.

Tags: combinatorics

> Five friends $-\mathrm{P}, \mathrm{Q}, \mathrm{R}, \mathrm{S}$ and $\mathrm{T}-$ go to a movie and sit next to each other in a row. $P$ can only sit in $k$ of the five seats (with the others having no preference). If the number of different ways they can arrange their seats can be written as $n k$, what is $n$ ?

Instead of thinking about factorials as competing for limited n=5 chairs, I assume we think about using a factorial to solve this problem as the order of choosing someone, i.e. $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$ for the four people. The P person has k chairs to choose from. And the first selection of four and P's selection is independent so is multiplied.

The four friends and P are independently seated (multiplication rule) : $24 \cdot k=nk$.

Is this logic right?

Answer (score 1):

Your computation is good, and I think your analysis is also good, but your syntax seems a little *iffy*.

> And the first selection of four and P's selection is independent so is multiplied.

It isn't that the selection of four is independent of P's selection.  Instead it is that

- There are $k$ choices for P's selection.
- The $\color{red}{\text{number of choices}}$ for the remaining four people, $4!$, is in fact independent of P's choice.

That is, regardless of where P is seated, there will be $4!$ ways of seating the other $4$ people.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it another way to reach the same answer.  Ignoring the constraint, there are $5!=120$ ways to arrange the $5$ friends.  The constraint means that only $\dfrac k5$ of those arrangements are "good."  Therefore there are $\dfrac {120k}{5}=24k$ "good" arrangements.